# I want to store php ajax success return value in a variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**php file**

```
$('.routine-of-classes ul.nav li button').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                className : $(this).attr("className")
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('.get-class-id').text(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

**ajax file**

```
if(isset($_POST['className'])){
    $getSubId = $_REQUEST['className'];
    echo $getSubId;
}
```

I want to store the return into a variable name like `$class` what should I need to do?

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just assign it?

Comment: if you want to save it you may use $_SESSION

Comment: @MiladElyasi Like How? Can you please recommend me?